# What is the difference between “unique to” and “unique for”?

Tags: prepositions

For example is it better to say:

“This problem is not **unique to** Australia.”

than

“This problem is not **unique for** Australia.”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unique to* is an established expression. "Not unique to Australia" means "occurs not only in Australia, but other places too".

*Unique for* is not an established expression, but there's nothing wrong with it. I would interpret "not unique for Australia" as "as far as Australia is concerned, this is not unique", or more simply "this occurs more than once in Australia". It doesn't say anything about whether it occurs elsewhere, or how often.